# Как открыть новый mainWindow и закрыть уже открытый нажатием на кнопку?

Tags: python, qt

При запуске программы, открывается окно регистрации типа `mainWindow`. Необходимо, что бы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось новое окно `mainWindow` и закрывалось предыдущее.

---

[image: Первое окно]

---

[image: Второе окно]

---

Окно на втором скриншоте должно открываться нажатием на кнопку `Авторизоваться` на первом окне, вслед за тем первое окно должно закрыться.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys

class _kurs_stack():
    def __init__(self):

        # Второе окно к формате .ui
        self.Form1, self.Windows1 = uic.loadUiType("_kurs_stack.ui")
        self.win1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        self.windows1 = self.Windows1()
        self.ui1 = self.Form1()
        self.ui1.setupUi(self.windows1)
        self.windows1.show()
        self.win1.exec()

class _curs_tab():
    def __init__(self):
        # Первое окно в формате .ui
        self.Form, self.Windows = uic.loadUiType("curs_tab.ui")
        self.win = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        windows = self.Windows()
        self.ui = self.Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(windows)

        #Кнопка, нажатие которой должно открывать второе окно
        self.ui.auth.clicked.connect(self.open_from_auth)

        windows.show()
        self.win.exec()
    #Команда открытия второго окна
    def open_from_auth(self):
        self.twently=_kurs_stack()

firstly = _curs_tab()
```

---

Проблема в закрытии второго окна сразу после его открытия, даже без прогрузки виджетов.

Нужна подобная реализация, в которой окна, помимо открытия второго первым, работали независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Так Вы же два QApplication создаете. Вы их запускаете а одном процессе? Вам нужно QMainWindow создавать для второго окна. Или QProcess использовать, например.

Comment: @eugesh По сути, это должны быть два разных процесса, где второй процесс заменяет первый.

Comment: Я думаю, что Вам либо не нужно два процесса, либо их нужно запускать отдельно. В приведенном фрагменте нет этого кода.

Comment: @eugesh для данной задачи не нужны никакие процессы.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается использованием функции `hide()`.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys

class _kurs_stack():
    def __init__(self):

        # Второе окно к формате .ui
        self.Form1, self.Windows1 = uic.loadUiType("_kurs_stack.ui")
        self.win1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        self.windows1 = self.Windows1()
        self.ui1 = self.Form1()
        self.ui1.setupUi(self.windows1)
        self.windows1.show()
        self.win1.exec()

class _curs_tab():
    def __init__(self):
        # Первое окно в формате .ui
        self.Form, self.Windows = uic.loadUiType("curs_tab.ui")
        self.win = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        windows = self.Windows()
        self.ui = self.Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(windows)

        #Кнопка, нажатие которой должно открывать второе окно
        self.ui.auth.clicked.connect(self.open_from_auth)

        windows.show()
        self.win.exec()
    #Команда открытия второго окна
    def open_from_auth(self):
        self.twently=_kurs_stack()
        windows.hide()

firstly = _curs_tab()
```

Comment: Gelly Houp, очень некрасиво и не совсем правильно.

Comment: @S.Nick А какой альтеранативный вариант можете предложить?

Comment: Gelly Houp, предоставьте минимально-ВОСПРОИЗВОДИМЫЙ пример, который демонстрирует проблему и я попробую вам что-то предложить.